# Basics of strategy.short -- Why don't short entries trigger without prior long entry

Tags: pine-script

I am dabbling with very basics in pine-script and can't find a good explanation why short entries will not trigger for simple "strategy.short" criteria. I can trigger a short to flip a previously entered long position, but if I comment out the long trigger of the code, it shows "No Trades" when the script is run. I should be able to enter a short position straight away. Is there something I don't understand about how strategy.short works? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Same as strategy.long basically
A trade needs an entry AND an exit
By default, a long close a short and vice-versa
But if you only go long or short and you didn't set any SL or TP or custom exit, your trades will never exit - then the backtester will show "No Trades"

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue was in the overall strategy function call as I had the margin_short and margin_long property set to 100. Once I removed those properties, strategy.short was executing as expected.